# How to: Get text index from label by mouse position? C#

Tags: c#, text, cursor, position, label

I have a label that contains text like this:

> 00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3

So, as this is a label (i don't want to use a TextBox) i need to know the way for get the index of the text in the label in the position of the cursor.

Let's say that in the last text, the mouse was clicked upside the AA.

> 00 ***AA*** FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3
>   00 AA FA 08 0F FF 84 7A A7 22 27 94 73 9A 7F D3

Then, i need get the index of "AA", is there a way for do it?, (No matter if i've to use the Win32 API)

I really can't find anything...

I'm working with Windows Forms.

Comment: This will be a lot easier if you create a separate label for each hex pair.  If you use one label one option is to handle the MouseDown event (Click does not give you any position information) to determine where the user clicked, then determine what pair that coordinate represents by measuring the number of characters that correspond to that coordinate.

Comment: "*then determine what pair that coordinate represents by measuring the number of characters that correspond to that coordinate.*"

Can you give me a clue how to do it?, because with separated labels, the IDE gets extremely lag.

Comment: That was very bad advice.  You need to use a fixed pitch font, like Consolas or Courier so that the digits are in predictable positions.  Then all you need to know is the size of a letter to map the mouse position to a string index.  TextRenderer.MeasureText() to find out in Winforms.

Comment: _I don't want to use a TextBox_ __Why??__ Make it `read-only` and all is perfectly simple using the `GetCharIndexFromPosition` method. Do not work against the system!

Answer (score 1):

Is it winforms or WPF?

Have you tried using the onMouseMove event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and getting the location from the mousemoveeventargs? That should give a location. The you can calculate the font size and work out if you can divide the location by the number of charachters to find the position.

One thing to becareful of is, to make sure the font you use has characters with equal widths, many of them don't.

I wouldn't recommend the approach Im suggesting architecutally because its very hacky and is not likely to be reuseable for other things. It will also take a while to get rid of all of the errors.

I would recommend using WPF is possible, and using a listview with a template that makes into a grid. See this example here: http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2007/12/04/five-steps-to-wpf-data-visualisation/ That example shows how a listbox can have its appearance changed to place elements in x,y co-ordinates. The listview defaultly supports checking if items are selected or not. If you are stuck with winforms maybe, my orginal approach is ok, or maybe dynamically generating lots of labels is better.